# Cannot install streamlit in Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages

Tags: python-3.x, pip, streamlit

im trying to install streamlit where my python is installed which is - `C:\Program Files\Python311\`

the default pip install location is `c:\users\arpan malik\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages` 
and streamlit is already in that directory but it is not the location where python is installed

when i run the command in vsc with admin privileges -

`pip install -target="C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages"`

streamlit to change the directory, it gives error -

```
`ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arpan Malik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arpan Malik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Arpan Malik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 507, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "C:\Users\Arpan Malik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 517, in _handle_target_dir
    ensure_dir(target_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Arpan Malik\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 107, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "<frozen os>", line 215, in makedirs
  File "<frozen os>", line 215, in makedirs
  File "<frozen os>", line 215, in makedirs
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "<frozen os>", line 225, in makedirs
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Program Files\\projectsp\\arget=C:'`
```

pip install streamlit gives error-
`Requirement already satisfied: streamlit in c:\users\arpan malik\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
pip install --target=C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages streamlit
```

(Removed the quotes and changed "-target" to ["--target"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-t), which should replace the package if it already exists in that location with the newest version)